# Terraform state storing in S3 using backend

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created S3 bucket and Dynamodb to store Terraform state file and enable the locks.

Now I was trying to initialize using terraform init,getting below error. Please find the backend.tf and main.tf files(I used these two files to store state file into s3 bucket)

Initializing the backend...

Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
providing credentials for the AWS Provider

Note: I used same Access key and secret access key for creation of S3 bucket and DynamoDB.(Created user and provided Admin access to that user)

###########
cat main.yml

provider "aws" {

```
access_key = "Access_Key_Here"

secret_key = "Secret_key_here"

region = "us-east-1"
```

}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {

```
   ami           = "ami-2757f631"

   instance_type = "t2.micro"
```

}

##########

#### cat backend.tf

terraform {

```
  backend "s3" {

    bucket = "bucket_name_here"

    key    = "terraform.tfstate"

    dynamodb_table = "table_name_here"

    region = "us-east-1"

  }
```

}

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Your main.yml file should be main.tf. Terraform only reads .tf files.

Comment: Sorry I mentioned yaml file here, but I used tf file only

Comment: The credentials for the backend and the provider need to be configured separately if you are providing credentials hard coded like this. But instead you should avoid hard coding credentials into your Terraform config (what happens if you check them into source control? Or share the file accidentally with someone else?) and use the SDK provided means of injecting credentials such as the SDK credentials/config files or environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd suggest navigating(in terminal) to folder where your terraform script resides and doing a command "aws configure" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html)
and then entering your creds.
hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by explaining why they need to do that and why what they've tried doesn't work. If you could expand on different ways to provide credentials and why it's a bad idea to hard code credentials in your Terraform files then it would be a good answer.

Comment: @RolandsG. It was working for me. Thanks for your help. Here Could you clarify my doubt. Why we need to configure the credentials as we already defining in terraform main.tf right, so why it is required again

Comment: @kaka: Ideally we should do aws configure only, if its there no need to specify creds in main.tf file. Terraform automatically pick creds from aws config.  There was bug initially in Terraform 0.11 where we need specify creds explicitly also but in 0.12 it is solved.